# Can I build Docusaurus site in development mode?

Tags: docusaurus

I have many pages in my Docusaurus v2 site with:

```yaml
draft: true
```

And I can view these by starting Docusaurus on my local machine like so:

```
yarn start
```

For the production build, these are omitted, since in production the site is built with:

```
yarn build
```

However, we have Netlify doing previews, so it would be nice to have a development version of the site containing the draft pages available in preview.

Is there a way of doing something like:

```
yarn build --mode=dev
```

Which would do a full build but in development mode rather than production?

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: not really.  In the end we removed the draft tag since lots of links were breaking.  We added a header in the draft pages to warn people they were looking at draft material.  Not the answer you were looking for probably, sorry.